# What is $\sinh^{-1}(\sin 3 \theta)=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm confused between the regular and hyperbolic sine functions ($\sin(x), \sinh(x)$) so I need help to solve this problem, as given in the title.

What are the $\sinh^{-1}(x), \sin(x)$ functions? Do both work the same?

Comment: Please give some more context for this problem -- ideally by quoting (and naming) the source you found it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sinh^{-1}t= \log(t+\sqrt{1+t^2}).$$

The term

$$\sqrt{1+\sin^23\theta}$$ leads to no particular simplification.

Comment: Thanks ........